# Specifying a different foreign key in a model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Staff and Hospital, in a belongs_to has_many relationship. A hospital has many staff. My staff table look like this:

```
class CreateStaffs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :staffs do |t|
      t.string :Title
      t.string :FirstName
      .
      .
      .
      t.integer :hospital_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Can't I specify a different foreign key, such as hospital_name?

Thanks

Comment: I really discourage you from using camel case names in Rails. You should rename `Title` to `title` and `FirstName` to `first_name`

Comment: Thank you for this advice @coorasse

Comment: Do you have a field `hospital_name` in "staffs" table? Or do you intend to add it?

Comment: I want to drop hospital_id and have hospital_name instead @JagdeepSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create the table like this:

```
create_table :staffs do |t|      
  ...
  t.string :hospital_name
end

add_foreign_key :staffs, :hospitals, column: :hospital_name, primary_key: :name
```

where with `primary_key: :name` you reference the column name of the `hospitals` table.